# How to set text in textbox jquery

Tags: jquery

I know to get the value of text box is like

```
$("#text").val();
<input type="text" id="text" />
```

But I want to enter `-` after a few numbers like if I enter 021 (three numbers) it should put - after it like `021-` `012-` it.

This is what I have done.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#text").on('focus',function()
        {
if((this).val() == "021"){
$("#text").text('-');
}
}
}
```

But this method  isn't working neither I believe it is on right way. Can anyone do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you enter inside an `input` element is only the value and isn't the HTML or `.text()` of the element. Instead keep using `.val()` and do:

```
$("#text").val($("#text").val()+"-");
```

Mention of this is noted in the jQuery documentation for [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/):

> The `.text()` method cannot be used on form inputs or scripts. To set or get the text value of `input` or `textarea` elements, use the `.val()` method.

Comment: There is also a part of question where we have to put - after three numbers so can you show or fix it?

Comment: @Matt Similar to entering a phone number, such as `123456789` will become `123-456-789`? Along with that do you want it to be applied after the user is done typing (`blur`) or have them placed in while typing these numbers?

Comment: Have them applied whilst typing! And only after first three numbers only. Like My regex is like this "/^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{8}$/"

Comment: @Matt You can simply use `<input id="text" pattern="/^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{8}$/" />` for HTML5.

Comment: Oh God! Why didn't I get this before!

Comment: Can you fiddle it please?

Comment: @Matt Opps sorry I was thinking validation there, anyways [this will work](https://jsfiddle.net/739bda3w/1/).

Comment: Thank you :) appreciated a lot

Comment: @Matt No problem you could add on `if($(this).val().length > 12) $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, 12))` to the end if you want to force it to be only 12 characters long as well.

Comment: Yess I did that! :) really helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#text').keyup(function() {
    var val = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
    var newVal = '';
    while (val.length > 3) {
        newVal += val.substr(0, 3) + '-';
        val = val.substr(3);
    }
    newVal += val;`enter code here`
    this.value = newVal;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ssthil/nY2QT/

Comment: I appreciate the effort but I only need - after first three numbers. This is the regex     "/^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{8}$/"